# What is the running time of these functions?

Tags: python, master-theorem

What is the running time?

```
def a(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return a(n/2)
```

My guess T(n) = T(n/2) + 1, then use master theorem.

---

How about this function:

```
def b(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(a(i))
```

This is my guess.

T(n) = nT(n/2) + 1

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I just need a theoretical time complexity.

Comment: when you say n/2 are you taking the floor?

Comment: It matters because the `/` operator's behaviour isn't the same on Python 2 and Python 3. Don't tag any language if it's not relevant.

Comment: No it is not. A theoretical time complexity measures the number of operations. Big O notation was made way before Python.

Comment: The number of operations depends on what the operations do. What the / operator does depends on the version of python. Therefore the number of operations depends on the version of python.

Comment: Your "theorical" code changes depending on which Python version you use. The theorical code is `return a(n/2)` in Python 2 and `return a(float(n)/2)` in Python 3. __It doesn't do the same thing at all.__

Comment: n/2 return a floor function.

Comment: Then the big-O is just log(n)

Comment: Was my T(n) correct?

Comment: Chad and Vincent, you are completely mistaken. Big-O complexity measures the rate at which the time taken by a function grows as its inputs grow. Whether / does float or integer division is **totally irrelevant** to that, as whichever it does, it is a *constant* factor and therefore ignored in big-O.

Comment: Can someone here just help me with my T(n) function.

Comment: @DanielRoseman nonsense. If / does floating point division then a(1) will infinitely recurse and will never result in a value for which n%2==0. Therefore there is no upper bound on that input.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Exactly, and that's why it's important in this case. The pseudo-code can be interpreted either as `return f(a, 2)` or `return g(a, 2)` depending on which version of Python it is. It is essential to know if we're calling `f` or `g` to calculate the complexity.

Comment: I didn't rate anything down.. Nor am I 'butt hurt'.

Comment: @user3773246:  Name-calling is inappropriate for Stack Overflow.  Please refrain from doing so in the future.

Comment: @user3773246 I voted this down because the question is unclear and cannot be accurately answered until you clarify exactly what you want. I'll remove my downvote once you edit your question. It has nothing to do with butthurtness, only with lack of rigor.

Comment: I think python 3 only return a float if n = 3.0. If n = 3, then it returns an integer

Comment: @user3773246  In Python 3, `3 / 2` is `1.5`.

Comment: That's the behavior for python 2. Python 3 will always return a float if the result should be a float.

Comment: @DanielRoseman:  On my computer running Python 3 given `x = 3`, doing `while x: x /= 2` iterates 1077 times.  Using Python 2 it iterates twice.

Comment: I am not a programmer. I am a math major. This question was given to me in pseudocode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one is O(logN) second one is O(NlogN).

1) You're cutting the problem in half every iteration. So the total number of times you iterate is:

i such that 2**i = N, in math i = logN in base 2. There for O(logN)

2) You're iterating through the entire list of size N so O(N) but you are calling a logN function on every iteration. So we are calling a logN function N times. This is O(NlogN).

Comment: Will the algorithm degenerate?

Comment: I was really hoping to get a formal proof using master theorem with T(N)

Comment: The second one is NlogN